# Jmeter, over writing data to file if it exists using jsr223 postProcessor

Tags: file, testing, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

```js
def file= new File(path + 'fileName.csv');
 List.unique().each { element ->
  file<< element << newLine
  }
```

Now the script is appending the file
But i want to clear all the data and over write the fileName.csv if it already exists 
If the file doesn't exists, create the file and write data to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to delete the file prior to writing to it via i.e. [Files.deleteIfExists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists-java.nio.file.Path-) function Add the next line to your script which will remove the file if it's present already:

```
java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath())
```

Full code just in case:

```
def file = new File(path + 'fileName.csv');
java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(new File().toPath())
List.unique().each { element ->
    file << element << newLine
}
```

See [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) for more hints